# Video with overflow not hidden at mobile

Tags: html, css, video, mobile

I have some problems doing changes on this site http://rocainternacional.org/2018/ In mobile, you can scroll to the right. Why it's happening? I want to make the video overflow hidden and something like size cover too..

```css
.body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.titulos {
 margin-top: 200px;
 padding: 0 100px;
 margin-bottom: 200px;
}
.titulos2 {
 margin-top: 300px;
 padding: 0 100px;
 margin-bottom: 200px;
}
.titulo-1 {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
 color: rgb(0, 153, 120);
}
.titulo-1 h2 {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 padding: 20px;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding-left: 70px;
 font-size: 35px;
}
.titulo-2 {
 background-color: rgba(0, 153, 120, 0.5);
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.titulo-2 h2 {
 margin-top: 0 !important;
 font-size: 30px;
 padding: 50px;
 padding-left: 70px;
}
.boton-right {
 display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.titulo-boton {
 background-color: #001F4A;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding: 15px 30px;
}
.titulo-boton a {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 20px
}

.footer-title {
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.item-1, 
.item-2, 
.item-3 {
 position: absolute;
  display: block;
 /*top: 2em;*/
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-size: 2em;

 animation-duration: 10s;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1{
 animation-name: anim-1;
}

.item-2{
 animation-name: anim-2;
}

.item-3{
 animation-name: anim-3;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
 0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  8.3%,25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
 0%, 33.33% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  41.63%, 58.29% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  66.66%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
 0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
 .titulo-1 {
  width: 350px;
 }

 .item-1, .item-2, .item-3 {
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 50px !important;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1700px) {
 .item-1, .item-2, .item-3 {
  width: 55%;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
 }
}

.text-blue {
 color: #337ab7 !important;
}

.opinion {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
       <!-- HTML CODE -->
       <!-- Here are the slider elements -->
       <!-- In desktop overflow: hidden works fine, but in mobile it doesnt -->

   <div class="container titulos" id="slideshow">
    <div class="row titulo-1">
     <h2>Bienvenidos a R.O.C.A. Internacional</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row titulo-2" style="height: 200px">
     <h2 class="item-1 no-padding-left">Capacitación profesional en todas las especialidades de la Odontología con Certificación Universitaria.</h2>
     <h2 class="item-2 no-padding-left">Diplomados de alto nivel, dictado por docentes de reconocimiento intenacional.</h2>
     <h2 class="item-3 no-padding-left">Red Odontológica de Capacitación Internacional.</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row boton-right">
     <div class="titulo-boton">
      <a href="" class="">Conocer más</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

In desktop the overflow: hidden works fine, but in mobile it doesnt..
Any suggest?

EDIT: I added this meta tag to the head and it did the trick

NOTE: How i put this post as done?

Comment: You should try giving it a max-width property, background-size: cover or background-repeat: no-repeat

Comment: tried but nothing happens.. I think it's for the sliding words on the middle, when they get out of the screens it becomes scrolleable, but i added overflow: hidden on it and nothing..

Comment: You should post the code that you used for the placement of the video just as some context

Comment: Done, i tried to cut some code and here it's.. In desktop overflow: hidden works perfect.. But in mobile it doesnt..

Answer (score 0):

Try body tag overflow hidden..

Comment: Try overflow-x:hidden

Answer (score 0):

This meta tag did the trick

Now on mobile it works perfect..